# Liferay Exception

Tags: java, liferay, jboss7.x

Receiving exception after changing the database.

There are two application server with host name prodwpas01 and prodwpas02 respectively.

The following exception are being generated by Liferay

```
20:45:49,853 INFO  [MSC service thread 1-13][BaseReceiver:64] Accepted view [prodwpas02-59913|12] [prodwpas02-59913, prodwpmw02-20897, prodwpas01-18001]
20:45:49,863 ERROR [Incoming-3,shared=liferay][NAKACK2:766] failed to deliver message [dst: <null>, src: prodwpas02-59913 (2 headers), size=889 bytes]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageBusUtil._sendMessage(MessageBusUtil.java:202)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageBusUtil.sendMessage(MessageBusUtil.java:90)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.cluster.messaging.ClusterForwardMessageListener.receive(ClusterForwardMessageListener.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.cluster.ClusterForwardReceiver.receive(ClusterForwardReceiver.java:44)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.invokeCallback(JChannel.java:749)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:710)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:1025)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER.up(STATE_TRANSFER.java:178)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:181)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:400)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:418)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:896)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:245)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST.up(UNICAST.java:414)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.handleMessage(NAKACK2.java:763)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:574)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2$1.run(NAKACK2.java:856)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In `portal-ext.properties` following lines are turned on but still receiving the exception

```
cluster.link.enabled=true
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
lucene.replicate.write=true
```

Comment: "after changing the database"... please give some detailed steps to reproduce and the Liferay version that you're using. What do you do when this message comes up?

Comment: Previously the liferay was pointed to a different database server. Now I have changed the database server and configured the Liferay as well. Liferay version is EE 6.1 and when I am restarting the jboss server then I am getting this exceptions.

Comment: With EE, why don't you open a support ticket? The team will know what questions to ask and probably get to the root cause quickly. Are all cluster nodes pointing to the same database? Was there also a change in database vendor? Also: This rather looks like a cluster communication issue than a database related one

Comment: Yes all the cluster node are pointing to the same database. No the database vendor is same. Is there a way to solve this? Are you saying the the prodwpas02 is inaccessible from prodwpas01 and vice versa?

Comment: Not sure. I assume that the log is from prodwpas01? It's not db related, rather cluster communication that we see here. Please open a support ticket as you're on EE - the support team will have better questions at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.